# Create scheduled task for next day in vbscript

Tags: vbscript

Need to create scheduled task in vbscript.
The Schedule task need to run 12:00 AM next day. The bellow script creates the sch task with the current day not the next day

```
Set wShell = CreateObject ("Wscript.Shell") 
wShell.Run "SchTasks /Create /SC ONCE /TN ""TestmyTask"" /TR ""C:\Temp\test.vbs"" /ST 00:00", 0
```

Please help me

Answer (score 1):

Use the `/sd` parameter, as per the documentation [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490996.aspx)